I'm looking for the name of an anime that I saw on TV in Italy over 20 years ago
I'm looking for the name of an anime that I saw on TV in Italy 20+ years ago. It is likely a show from the 80's. 
The scene I saw was a very large man who tried to break into a castle. He seemed to possess supernatural strength.  A young princess or a queen with a metal mask stood on the castle stairwell with soldiers guarding the entry. As the attacker smashed his through the gate/wall, the soldiers attacked him with their blades and axes. Their weapons have no impact. He killed them simultaneously with ease. He used his finger and applied little pressure to the woman's mask. It broke off revealing her face. She killed herself with a blade. 
There was a flashback of her running away from a pack of wolves when she was a little girl. She reached cliff and she was surrounded. One wolf dived toward her and a flying rock stuck it and killed it. The other wolves surrounded the man who threw the rock and he killed them without effort and walked away.
Back to the present scene in the castle, as the woman died, the large man who broke into the castle was enraged. The dialogue was dubbed in Italian, I couldn't understand any of it.
I believe the large man who attacked the castle wanted to take the woman but she was in love with the man who saved her from a pack of wolves when she was a girl. Her suicide angered her would be captor who called the other man's name and wanted to seek revenge.
I thought it was an episode from Fist of North Star but I don't recall there was such episode.

Depending on how well you are remembering the show, you might be thinking of Berserk.
Near the end of the anime adaptation Guts almost single-handedly breaks into a castle dungeon to rescue his captain and friend, Griffith, who is a very beautiful man and his face has been trapped in an iron mask. After the rescue, Guts has to fight his way back up the stairs and effortlessly murders many of the guards trying to force their way down. And later on, Griffith does in fact kill himself. 

If someone could help me out by spoilering my relevant blocks.  I have no clue how to do it.

No, it is not Berserk. I have seen all of the Berserk. This is older. Definitely around the time of Hokuto no Ken (Fist of North Star). The characters look like design of Toei Animation with eyes, nose, and other facial feature similar to Dragon Quest, Dragon Ball Z.,,,
